# Extract a generic value using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following interface in my project.

```
public interface Setting<T>
{
    T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Using reflection, I would like to examine properties that implement this interface and extract Value.

So far I have written this, which successfully creates a list of properties that implement Setting.

```
var properties = from p in obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                 where p.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IAplSetting<>))
                 select p;
```

Next I would like to do this: (Please ignore the undefined variables, you can assume that they really do exist in my actual code.)

```
foreach (var property in properties)
{
    dictionary.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(_theObject, null).Value);
}
```

The problem is that GetValue returns an object. In order to access Value, I need to be able to cast to `Setting<T>`. How would I get Value and store it, without needing to know the exact type of T?

Comment: Dictionary is strongly typed - if you do not know T how did you create the dictionary of type `Dictionary<string, T>` ?

Comment: I too am a bit confused as to your goal, I've supplied an answer but I feel like there may be a better approach.

Comment: It's a Dictionary of `Dictionary<string, object>`.

Comment: It's actually an ExpandoObject, but it was easier for the example to show it as a Dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could continue this approach with one more level of indirection:

```
object settingsObject = property.GetValue(_theObject, null);
dictionary.Add(
    property.Name,
    settingsObject.GetType().GetProperty("Value")
                            .GetValue(settingsObject, null));
```

---

If you're using `dynamic` (re: your comment about `ExpandoObject`), this can be much simpler:

```
dynamic settingsObject = property.GetValue(_theObject, null);
dictionary.Add(property.Name, settingsObject.Value);
```

Comment: That's a handy trick. I hadn't thought of using dynamic like that. Thanks!